# deploying vue in apache server

Tags: apache, vue.js, virtualhost

I have trouble with deploying vue app to apache2. I have backend in this server(backand has written in .Net). And my backend app named my-finecard.online. For this backend I did api.conf and the api conf looked like:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
  RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost my-finecard.online:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
  ServerName my-finecard.online
  ServerAlias my-finecard.online
  
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}api-error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}api-access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Also for my frontend I change my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and added to this conf that strings:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Therefore I did `.htaccess` file and added to the file that strings:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have dist folder like this which genered after npm run build:

In conclusion, when i start my server, and go to url: https://my-finecard.online/
I have the 404 error. How I could correct the problem?

Comment: Is it working with the IP itself?

Comment: Also when you create the config you need to enable it with `a2enconf api.conf` then restart. Did you do that?

Comment: @n1md7 yep, I restarted. But i dont understand first question(

Comment: I assume u have VPS hosting. If the server works properly u have to be able to reach the endpoint from your browser using server's IP. Binding IP to the domain name is the other thing. verify the first step and then make sure CNAME is correctly setup and your domain provider knows what NS server to point.